# Spring Boot - How to display Static Resources Before Logging In?

Tags: spring-boot

Alright, I have searched every answer that talks about serving static resources from a spring boot application, but nothing has solved my issue. I am trying to use a css stylesheet and an image on my login page, however, they won't load. When I check the network tab in dev tools, I see that I am getting a 302 response from the server and its saying the new location is http://localhost:8080/login

My thought is that it can't access the files because of the security we have on the application. Here is the structure of my project:

[image: Project Structure]

I have messed around with the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

[image: WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter]

And the Resource Handler:

[image]

But I have had no luck. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the folder of your static resources in your security configuration like:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {

    // other security config
    .antMatchers(..., "/resources/*").permitAll()

}
```

**UPDATE**: You shouldn't remove `.anyRequest().authenticated()` at all because then everything is not secured. Try to add it to your security configuration again but after your permitted the access to all your pages which are not secured (e.g. `/login`, etc.).

To allow the user for your resources, try:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {

    // other security config 
    // ... are your other URLs which are not secured with authentication
    .antMatchers(..., "/resources/**").permitAll()

}
```

Comment: I tried adding this like you stated, but still getting a 302! Doesn't antMatchers just permit users to access these pages with certain roles? In this case, i am permitting all roles access to those antMatchers...Appreciate the response though!

Comment: can you publish your project on GitHub or is it a private/enterprise project? So I could have a detailed look at it

Comment: rieckpil, did you take a look?

Comment: not right now as you said it worked, should i take a look or is it working right now?

Comment: Yeah, that would be great, because right now i dont have any security on the website. You can hit any page if you know the url... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got it! With the help of @rieckpil, I found the issue. It didn't have to do with antMatchers() that I can tell. It started working as soon as I removed the:

```
.anyRequest().authenticated()
```

Thanks all!

Comment: with removing this line you are 'opening' all your secured views/endpoints. Did you check your secured pages after you removed this line?